# Keep cache of table column in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have table component and i can customize of table column. 
I can relocate and also hide/show of table column.

So how can i store user customizing of table column in client cache?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Kindly take a look around and see how to ask a proper, valid question.

Comment: what do you mean by customizing ? show hide table at run time ? or based on some use role ?

Comment: I have a table and i can hide or show of column. Im doing every customizing of column. just the store of last table customizing. When user login to system, i will show last table(grid) customizing to user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that I don't know what package are you using to handle "table customization", I think that you could save your "custom configuration" on the local storage using `localStorage.set('user custom table configuration', JSON.stringify(configObject))`.

To retrieve it, on the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method, you can read it and save it in the state with `localStorage.get('user custom table configuration')`. Consider that:

- it might not exist (never customized the table before), so you must be able to handle a default case;
- it will be a string, so you need to `JSON.parse` it;

Comment: It will be solution for me. Thanks a lot.